# Invalid custom update query defined in Spring Data JPA CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a custom JPQL query in a Spring CrudRepository that's not working.

This is my entity class, PK class and CrudRepository interface for the entity:

```
@Entity(name = "TBL_PRINCIPAL_CREDENTIAL")
public class PrincipalCredential {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PrincipalCredentialPK principalCredentialPK;

    // ...getter & setter for principalCredentialPK
}

@Embeddable
public class PrincipalCredentialPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private String principalTypeID;

    @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_ID", nullable = false)
    private String principalID;

    @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer credentialID;

    @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private String credentialTypeID;

    // ...getters & setters for all fields...
}

@Transactional
public interface PrincipalCredentialRepository extends CrudRepository<PrincipalCredential, PrincipalCredentialPK> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update PrincipalCredential pc set pc.principalCredentialPK.principalID =:newPrincipalID " +
            "where pc.principalCredentialPK.principalID =:oldPrincipalID and pc.principalCredentialPK.principalTypeID =:principalType")
    void updatePrincipalID(@Param("oldPrincipalID") String oldPrincipalID, @Param("newPrincipalID") String newPrincipalID,
                           @Param("principalType") String principalType);
}
```

When I start my project using SpringBoot the repository bean cannot be instantiated and I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'principalCredentialRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void com.consorsbank.services.banking.caas.repositories.PrincipalCredentialRepository.updatePrincipalID(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void com.consorsbank.services.banking.caas.repositories.PrincipalCredentialRepository.updatePrincipalID(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: PrincipalCredential is not mapped [update PrincipalCredential pc set pc.principalCredentialPK.principalID =:newPrincipalID where pc.principalCredentialPK.principalID =:oldPrincipalID and pc.principalCredentialPK.principalTypeID =:principalType]
```

Also for another repository this query is working, the difference is that the PK of the other entity is simpler and both ids are provided there...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_PRINCIPALS")
public class Principal implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PrincipalPK principalPK;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PrincipalType principalType;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Integer userID;

    @Column(name = "VALID_UNTIL")
    private Date validUntil;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "ZAAS_TBL_PRINCIPAL_CREDENTIAL",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PRINCIPAL_ID"), @JoinColumn(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPE_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CREDENTIAL_ID"), @JoinColumn(name="CREDENTIAL_TYPE_ID")})
    public Set<Credential> credentials;

    // ...getters and setters...
}

@Embeddable
public class PrincipalPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private String principalTypeID;

    @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_ID", nullable = false)
    private String principalID;

    // ...getters and setters
}

@Transactional
public interface PrincipalsRepository extends CrudRepository<Principal, PrincipalPK> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update Principal p set p.principalPK.principalID =:newPrincipalID " +
            "where p.principalPK.principalID =:oldPrincipalID and p.principalPK.principalTypeID =:principalType")
    void updatePrincipalID(@Param("oldPrincipalID") String oldPrincipalID, @Param("newPrincipalID") String newPrincipalID,
                           @Param("principalType") String principalType);
}
```

So the above query is working... 
Could someone please point out what I'm missing for the query defined in the PrincipalCredentialRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity definition seems to be wrong. Use the following annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_PRINCIPAL_CREDENTIAL")
public class PrincipalCredential {
//...
```

Comment: Indeed that was the problem... couldn't see it :) Thanks!